# SQL get values from xml with same node name

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath

I have a stored procedure that run in about 20 seconds, it seems extremely ineffecient. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas of how this could be done better.

XML

```
<Values>
 <Required>
  <Name Type="WS">ganderson</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">mhoffmann</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">lmcswain</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">jbranham</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">gsimpson</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">jbennett</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">bdrum</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">mtrott</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">acannon</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">dgantt</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">evalone</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">flyons</Name>
  <Name Type="WS">saheavner</Name>
 </Required>
</Values>
```

Query

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Usernames varchar(200),xmldata xml,FNActionID int,SubscriberType varchar(max))
  INSERT INTO @tab (Usernames) 
  SELECT SUBSTRING(Active_Dir_Name,5,LEN(Active_Dir_Name)) FROM USERS WHERE LEN(ACTIVE_DIR_NAME) > 5 AND IsEnabled = 1

  UPDATE @tab
  SET xmldata = @tag 

  UPDATE @tab
  SET FNActionID = @FnActionID

 INSERT INTO @MainTable
  SELECT xmldata.value('(/Values/Required/Name[text()=sql:column("Usernames")])[1]','varchar(max)'),FNActionID
  FROM @tab
  WHERE xmldata.exist('/Values/Required/Name[text()=sql:column("Usernames")]') = 1
```

The goal here is im using the table users, the column actived_dir_name and joining this on my xml using the SELECT xmldata.value. The problem is this is not within the same table, so i have to put both values within a temp table so xml knows where to look.

The thing is, I have about 20 different xml entries that I am checking against this entire users column on a different database, and it is running slow, as it should.

It seems like this is a backward way to do it. I know the code doesn't make sense, if you have any pointed questions let me know and I will answer as best as possible.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the XML sample? The xpaths "/Configuration/Values/Required/Name" and "/Configuration/Name" don't resolve for that snippet. for a complete solution, could you fill those bits in?

Comment: sorry about that, the entire xml is rather large, i fixed the code.

Comment: Does my answer help alleviate the problem any?

Comment: it helps a little. im looking into how i can better incorporate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an outer apply first and then binding the two in the where clause.

```
SELECT tag.name.value('.','nvarchar(20)')
FROM @tab tab
    outer apply tab.xmldata.nodes('/Values/Required/Name') tag(name)
where tab.Usernames = tag.name.value('.','nvarchar(20)')
```

Also, if it doesn't already exist, consider an [XML Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx).

Comment: in a way, but is it possible to not have to refrence xml that is in the same table, like can I refrence two different tables.

Comment: My answer doesn't reference the xml in the table, it uses your @TAG XML variable, and uses .nodes() on it.

Comment: right, I guess my question is if @TAG was not an xml variable, but rather an xml column in a table.

Comment: Oh, well I'm unsure here, there's lots of questions that pop up, for example, is the data we see in your question the same structure and data for each row? for example, can it be counted on that /Values/Required/Name[1] results in the same name for each row? or not? If not, perhaps it would behoove you to select from your base table with the xml first, and use it's xml column data with .nodes() applied. I'll try a sample to make sure that works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get diferents values from nodes with same name:

```
xmldata.value('(/Values/Required/Name/text())[1]','varchar(max)') AS name1
```